# Метод, который переводит из кирпичного языка

Tags: c#, методы

Доброго времени суток, господа!

Только начал изучение программирования на C#. Есть задание: создать метод, который переводит на кирпичный язык и обратно. С переводом НА кирпичный я разобрался, а как обратно? Помогите

```
using System;

public static class Trans
{   
    private static char[] _vovels = new char[]{ 'а', 'о', 'е', 'и', 'ю', 'я', 'у', 'э'};

    private static bool IsVovel(char c)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < _vovels.Length; i++)
        {
            if(_vovels[i] == c)
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static string ToBrick(string str)
    {
        var result = "";

        for(var i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            result = result + str[i];

            if(IsVovel(str[i]) == true)
                result = result + 'с' + str[i];
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static string FromBrick(string str)
    {
        // здесь нужно сделать перевод ИЗ кирпичного.
    }
}

public class App
{   
    public void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Trans.ToBrick("Привет, дубина"));
        // Перевод НА кирпичный будет таким: "Присивесет, дусубисинаса"
    }
}
```

Comment: Было бы неплохо описать правила перевода и текст размещать текстом, а не картинкой.

Comment: Точно так же, как и добавлял. Только пробегись по строке и удали каждый 2ой слог

Comment: Стыдно признаться, но я не знаю как убрать слог. Добавить -- без проблем, но убавить -- хз. Я только представляю себе как хардкод здесь написать под каждый частный случай, но это глупо.

Comment: @IgorYarovoy Я дополнил ответ еще одним вариантом, может быть пригодится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант можно использовать [регулярные выражения](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var text = "Привет, дубина";
var brickText = Regex.Replace(text, "([аоеиюяуэ])", "$1c$1");
var normalText = Regex.Replace(brickText, "([аоеиюяуэ])c\\1", "$1");
```

Пример можно посмотреть [тут](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IZGkcM).

**UPDATE**

Еще как вариант, без регулярных выражений, можно сделать так:

```
private static readonly List<string> Vovels = new List<string> { "а", "о", "е", "и", "ю", "я", "у", "э" };

public static void Main()
{
    var text = "Привет, дубина";

    var brickText = text;
    Vovels.ForEach(v => brickText = brickText.Replace(v, GetBrickTextForChar(v)));

    var normalText = brickText;
    Vovels.ForEach(v => normalText = normalText.Replace(GetBrickTextForChar(v), v));

}

static string GetBrickTextForChar(string textChar)
{
    return textChar + "с" + textChar;
}
```

Пример можно посмотреть [тут](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yFhjE2).